# DrawerLayout is hidden below the GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I try to implement the latest drawer layout from support library 13.
With the following code, the drawer is always showing below the gridview. Even I try to call bringToFront() still not working. Can help to find what's wrong? Thanks.

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

member_home_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/member_home_thumbnail_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp" >
    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The main activity:

```
public class BaseRootActivity extends BaseActivity {
    private DrawerLayout                    mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView                            mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle   mDrawerToggle;
    private String[]                            mMainMenus;

    public ListView getDrawerListView() {
        return this.mDrawerList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mMainMenus = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_menu_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mMainMenus));

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle("actionbar title");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle("drawer title");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }
...
```

in main fragment

```
public class MemberHomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {

    private GridView                            mGridListView;
    private UserThumbnailAdapter    memberAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.member_home_layout, container, false);

        mGridListView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.member_home_thumbnail_grid);
        mGridListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        memberAdapter = new UserThumbnailAdapter(this.getActivity(), null);
        mGridListView.setAdapter(memberAdapter);

        this.startLoading(); // load thumbnails

        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: This looks fine. Could you post how you are adding the fragment? You shouldn't have to call "bringToFront". The main thing is that your "left_drawer" comes after your "content_frame" in the xml, which it does. Are you doing any animations or z-aligning? My experience is coming from the v4 of the support library, but it should be the same.

Comment: the code is normal: getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MemberHomeFragment()).commit();

Comment: No animations or z-aligning (... i dunno how to z-align lol)

Comment: By adding different background colors to fragment container, gridview and drawer, it turns out that gridview is on the top, drawer in the middle and the fragment container is on the bottom. Any clue?

Comment: Try putting this in your onActivityCreated method in your fragment: 
        mGridListView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.member_home_thumbnail_grid);
        mGridListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
 
        memberAdapter = new UserThumbnailAdapter(this.getActivity(), null);
        mGridListView.setAdapter(memberAdapter);
 
        this.startLoading(); // load thumbnails

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it fixed. But I cannot understand the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this isn't a problem with the way you are using the drawer layout as I mentioned earlier. It's a problem with the way you are using fragments. The way the FragmentManager works is you create a fragment transaction, and you tell the fragment transaction a set piece of work and then you commit it, so that it all happens at once.

When you add, remove, or in your case Replace a fragment you have to tell the FragmentManager where to put your fragment, and you were giving it the wrong location. You were telling it to put your fragment inside android.R.id.content, a place that ALL of the content on the screen lives inside. You only want to add a fragment to one your own containers. The fact that the ID you specified (android.R.id.content) begins with 'android', is a big giveaway that it is the android systems, and not yours.

You instead want to put it in the location inside of your navigation drawer that you specified, which is R.id.content_frame. You can see how you specified that in your xml above, which I will copy here for you:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
```

Comment: my bad... i never noticed the android.R part even with my own answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand but here is the issue:

As @spierce7 pointed out, the way I call fragment replacement is not correct (but why?)
My code is:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MemberHomeFragment()).commit();
```

and when I changed to:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new MemberHomeFragment()).commit();
```

It works.

Comment: See my answer that I'm about to post.